# Javascript is not being applied in cakePHP

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GBSZ8/297/) is the html and and javascript to be applied. The snippets are taken from the html generated by cakePHP and the javascript that is included in the view file. Everything works as expected in jsfiddle, but no action is being fired in cakePHP application.

The javascript is pasted in the top of the view file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#repeat').live('change', function(){
      if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
         $('#end-date').show();
     } else {
         $('#end-date').hide();
     }
 }); 
</script>
```

The form looks like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Event');?>

        <legend><?php __('Add Event'); ?></legend>

        <div id="first_input">
        <fieldset>
    <?php   
        echo $this->Form->input('project_id', array('label'=>'Project name')); 
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('label'=>'Employee'));
        echo $this->Form->input('hours', array('type'=>'text','size'=>'3'));
        echo $this->Form->input('minutes', array('type'=>'text', 'size'=>'3')); ?>
    </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="second_input">
    <fieldset>

    <?php   
        echo $this->Form->input('assignment', array('type'=>'textarea'));
        echo $this->Form->input('date', array('label' => 'Date', 'class'=>'datepicker', 'type'=>'text', 'value'=>$date));
        echo $this->Form->input('start_time', array('label'=>'Start Time', 'timeFormat' => '24', 'interval'=> '10', 'selected' => '00:00'));
        echo $this->Form->input('finish_time', array('label'=>'Finish Time (Not required)', 'timeFormat' => '24', 'interval'=> '10', 'selected' => '00:00')); 
        echo $this->Form->checkbox('Repeat', array('id'=>'repeat'));?>
    <div id="end-date" style="display:none">
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('finish_date', array('label' => 'End Date', 'class'=>'datepicker', 'type'=>'text', 'id' => 'end-date'));
        echo $this->Form->select('weekdays', array('1'=>'Monday', '2'=>'Tuesday', '3'=>'Wednesday', '4'=>'Thursday', '5'=>'Friday', '6'=>'Saturday', '7'=>'Sunday'), array('multiple'=>'checkbox'));?>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
        </div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
```

I really look forward in getting some hints for how to solve this.

Comment: There is no way to know what the problem is, as it cannot be reproduced from the info provided (the js fiddle works - as you mention in the question). Most likely there is another js error  (check for js errors in the console) which means the js code in the application isn't run at all.

Comment: Here is the error that I get:
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' [http://localhost/calendar/events/add/2/2013/9/5:144].

Comment: what version of jquery are you using.. `console.log($.fn.jquery)` will tell you. Either `$` isn't jquery at all or you are using a version which doesn't have `.live` (which wouldn't be too much of a surprise if you're using a recent version of jquery, it's been deprecated since version 1.7).

Comment: I am using version 1.10.2, but the console.log($.fn.jquery) in chrome says "undefined".

I am novice in jquery, but will try evertyhting to make it work.

Comment: That means you haven't loaded jquery at all.

Comment: BUt when I include the following code: if(typeof jQuery != 'undefined'){alert("loaded")};
I get the the alert with no problem.

Comment: So as I said, the jquery was loaded and the jQuery version was 1.10.2. What I got to know was that 'live' was not supported in this version and that I had to change it to 'on'. Now it is all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to know that 'live' was not supported in the jQuery version that I was using(1.10.2), it should have been changed to 'on'. So it is all good now, here is the proper code for a newer versions of jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#repeat').on('change', function(){
          if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
             $('#end-date').show();
         } else {
             $('#end-date').hide();
         }
     }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Always write Java script code at the bottom of the page.

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet.

Comment: Could you please create JsFiddle for that ?

Comment: It is solved now, the js fiddle is in the question. But that applies only to older versions of jQuery. For the newer ones 'live' should be replaced by 'on'

Answer (score 1):

To use jQuery code correctly you have to wrap the code around $(document).ready() block. As stated in the [documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/),

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Try to change your JS code into:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#repeat').live('change', function(){
          if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
             $('#end-date').show();
         } else {
             $('#end-date').hide();
         }
     }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried, unfortunatelly with no luck. No event is still being fired.

Comment: Here is the error that I get from the js errors notifier: TypeError:" Object [object Object] has no method 'live' "

Comment: This is the same as a now-deleted previous answer. `.live` isn't affected by whether the dom elements exist when the method is called - this isn't going to change anything. `.live` is also [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) replaced by [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).